# Why VI always starts in insert mode?

Tags: startup, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vi

At some point, whenever I use vi from the command line (windows 10/WSL) it starts up in insert mode, meaning that everything I usually do to navigate ends up adding stuff to the file, wasting time having to clean it up.

I didn't have a vimrc file, and there doesn't seem to be anything in my bash rc files to modify vi behavior. Any ideas what I may have done or any ideas how to stop this behavior? I'm using Ubuntu-20.04

FWIW, adding a .vimrc file with tab related settings didn't change it's behavior. I looked at the /etc/vimrc file, and nothing inside it seemed relevant.

Comment: As a usage question more than a development question, this is probably a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plowing through google search and trying everything I understand about configuring 'vim' and doing comparison tests, I think:

1. This behavior is specific to Windows Terminal when opening a WSL terminal. Using WSL's "native" terminal (i.e., clicking the "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" menu in the "Start" menu) doesn't have this problem.
2. My original motivation for switching to Windows Terminal is for its multi-tab feature. But this new behavior is crazy -- it works against years of my muscle memory of using "vi", and I'm almost certain that one day I'll accidentally update some configuration file while reading it in "vi". And, I cannot re-train a new muscle memory because all the rest of the UNIX world (e.g., when I SSH into a remote server) hasn't changed. This is like constantly switching between a Mac keyboard and a PC keyboard where the Ctrl key, etc., are in different places.

My solution: I switched to MobaXterm. It has multi-tab support, and is actually richer in features compared to Windows Terminal.

Comment: Actually, I had discovered that it was only the preview version of Windows Terminal, but obviously this got introduced into the non-preview version with the most recent release, though, I'm not sure it happens every time with the current non-preview version but it's really a major problem. I'll give Moba a try

Comment: FWIW, a release I installed today seems to fix this problem. It's even listed as a bug fix, so obviously they took it seriously enough to look into.

Answer (score 1):

I have been a long-suffering victim of this problem, but today decided to try to find a solution for it, and found this thread.  Since it did not have a real good solution, and other pages/threads did not either, I looked into the problem and found a solution I thought was worth sharing.

The short answer:  set your TERM variable to vt100

The default value is TERM=xterm-256color.  Either change TERM from your command line, or in your .bashrc or .bash_aliases file, just add the line

export TERM=vt100

The "export" is probably implied, but does not hurt to use it.

I actually just guessed that might work and so found this solution quickly.  But then I spent a lot more time investigating to see if there was a solution even better than that, or that explained why it worked, or why the problem occurred, and learned:
(1) The terminal emulator that runs with debian-on-WSL1 is a Windows Console, which was specifically designed to emulate a vt100, which an xterm is based on, but is missing some capabilities and as we can see, does not fully emulate the xterm that terminfo is targeting;
(2) Windows Terminal does not have the problem, it must have an improved design and does emulate an xterm more completely, so you could alternately start a Windows Terminal and run "wsl" or "debian" in a tab, and then would not have to change TERM to vt100;
(3) The bad behavior results from an unintentional "2R" vim command, as the bottom status bar shows "REPLACE" not "INSERT", and the "2" must be there because text typed in gets replicated once; so the "2R" probably is part of a control string that Windows Console does not support.

Comment: The original poster posted a comment above on 9-22-20 saying he installed a release that fixed the problem, but with debian on WSL1 on win10 the problem still is present, thus the need for a solution today.   Perhaps the "release" he is referring to is to run ubuntu on WSL2, which I also have installed, and does not exhibit the problem.  It could also be that ubuntu has changes in its terminfo database that debian does not, and maybe it has nothing to do with WSL1 vs. WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following:

```
alias | grep vim
sudo find / -name .vimrc 2>/dev/null
```

These commands should show you all the places to check, change the alias or fix the .vimrc files found.

Do you find it always going into edit mode, when you vim a file directly  and when you use vim as the git commit editor for example?

EDIT:

You could also try `which -a vim` or `whereis vim` to see if you have multiple versions. Or failing that `sudo find / -name vim 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Yeah, aliases were my first suspicion, none exist. The home directory vimrc and the etc vimrc are very simple and neither have anything that differs from a similar system's rc files (this other machine doesn't exhibit this behavior)   Strangely, it is almost as if vim receives an 'R' because it's actually replacing at the start

Comment: FWIW, I did uninstall and reinstall vi using apt-get and it didn't change behavior. I also moved all login RC files and logged in a separate time with no change to VI.

Comment: You mention vi and vimrc are we talking about vim or vi or both?

Comment: Well, my understanding is that vi really is vim and when I look at the final target for both vi and vim on that WSL instance, both point to /usr/bin/vim.basic   Both behave identically

Answer (score 0):

here is a better solution.  I downloaded the binary.
https://github.com/lxhillwind/vim-bin/releases/tag/v9.0.0978

Put the vim command in /usr/bin/vi

Put the runtime in:
/usr/local/share/vim/runtim

sudo apt remove vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny
sudo apt purge vim vim-common vim-doc vim-runtime vim-tiny

The second line actually gets rid of residual-defaults.
There is also a defaults.vim someplace on the system.  I just nuked it.

I went through and made sure there were no aliases or vi or vim configuration files, but still no luck.

This is a horrible solution, but the only thing that is keeping my sanity right now.

vi -c ":imap jj "

You can alias it in your .bashrc.   Looking into better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: the culprit file is /etc/vim/vimrc

For problems like this, and actually any other case when an app starts  with an undesirable configuration, all you need to do is to run the app under strace. Look through the trace for files being successfully opened most likely by the "openat" call. Here are the steps:

```
$ strace vi 2>xx
$ grep openat xx | grep rc
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/vim/vimrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/vim/vimrc.local", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/zdenek/.vimrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/zdenek/_vimrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/zdenek/.vim/vimrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/zdenek/.exrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
$ ls -l /usr/share/vim/vimrc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Apr  3 00:45 /usr/share/vim/vimrc -> /etc/vim/vimrc
$ sudo mv /etc/vim /etc/vim.bad
$ vi
$
```

Done. The problem is gone. If desired you can sift through the init files in the distribution and eliminate the offending entry. I prefer to write my own vim init file (~/.exrc)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Kozel's post https://stackoverflow.com/a/76187152/8840572 but it only worked for vi, for some reason; vim has the problem regardless.

For vi you can also run it with `vi --clean`, but then it won't read any of your private rc files.  This option doesn't fix the problem for vim.

From the same post, though, I noticed that if I run vi/vim under strace, the problem goes away for some odd reason.  So here's my hacky solution:

```
alias vi='strace --trace=exit vi'
alias vim='strace --trace=exit vim'
```

The --trace=exit option just tells strace to only trace the exit systemcall.  When you quit from vi/vim, strace will show the exit code, but that's it.